# array not updating within firebase once()

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase

I have an array `customers` declared outside of firebase `ref.once()` function.

`var customers = [];`

I am changing the value of the array within `ref.once()` and trying to access the modified value out of `ref.once()`. But it returns the initial value `[]`.

Here is my code

```
  var customers = [];
  var nameRef = new Firebase(FBURL+'/customerNames/');
  nameRef.once("value",function(snap){
      customers.push("test");
  });
  console.log(customers); // returns []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `once` callback is executed asynchronously and that the log statement is actually called before `customers.push("test");`. Try the following code to see the order in which the code is executed:

```
var customers = [];
var nameRef = new Firebase(FBURL+'/customerNames/');
nameRef.once("value",function(snap){
    customers.push("test");
    console.log("Inside of callback: " + customers); // returns [test]

    // At this point, you can call another function that uses the new value.
    // For example:
    countCustomers();
});
console.log("Outside of callback: " + customers); // returns []

function countCustomers() {
    console.log("Number of customers: " + customers.length);
}
```

Comment: But, i want to use the pushed values in array `customers` outside of `once()`. How it cane be achieved ?

Comment: The value won't change until the callback is executed. So you should call the appropriate code that needs the modified value from within the callback. You probably should explain better what you need, and/or post the ode that needs the modified value, to get a more specific explanation.

Comment: How can i know the callback has been completed executing? so that i can call another code that uses the array value?